# 'With the exceptions of' vs. 'with the exception of'

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

In a sentence listing a number of exceptions, do we still use 'with the exception of'?

> > Lake Champlain furnishes the only commercial fishing grounds in Vermont, with the exceptions of small catches of white fish in Lake Bomoseen, Lake St Catherine in Rutland county and Lake Memphremagog (from [link](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/exceptions)).
> >
> > With the exceptions of Queen Victoria, Edith Cavell and Boudicea, are there any public statues of women in London? ([article](https://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,,-2726,00.html) from The Guardian)

I did find a [discussion](https://painintheenglish.com/case/4737) on this topic. One commentor has has said '*Here are two examples from MWDEU, which says 'with the exception of' is commonly used as a synonym for 'except (for)':*

> > *with the exception of British Guiana and the Virgin Islands.*
> >
> > *... with the exception of cases of deliberate, premeditated theft*

I was unable to view the exact page on MWDEU to do further research on this.
But a quick Google search showed me that the other usage is [not uncommon](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=nBRhVqbaJeeK8QeooIPwAQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22with%20the%20exceptions%20of%22&start=0).

I have never seen the usage of 'with the exceptions of' before this. Are both these usages applicable? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, perfectly fine and in fairly common use.

Comment: If you have never encountered _"with the exceptions of"_, you have not read widely. That a silly mistake is common does not make it less silly, nor less easily avoided. There is no reason to intentionally introduce disagreement in number. If you can avoid doing so, you should. Use _exceptions_ when there are more than one, and _exception_ when there is one only.

Answer (score 2):

> I have never seen the usage of 'with the exceptions of' before this.

I agree with you. My Oxford dictionary says "with the exception of". Unfortunately, Guardian is notorious for their typo.

Comment: I checked Google Books, which initially claimed "about 2,050 results" for the sequence [with the **exception** of john and](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22with+the+exception+of+john+and%22), compared to just 7 for the explicitly pluralised [with the **exceptions** of john and](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22with+the+exceptions+of+john+and%22). On scrolling through the results, I discover there are actually only 19 hits for the former. So it's not exactly a slam dunk, but clearly most of us see ***with the exception of*** as a fixed phrase not to be messed about with.

Comment: Since the usage of ‘with the exceptions of’ [seems to be quite common](https://www.google.co.in/search?tbm=bks&q=%22with+the+exceptions+of+john+and%22&gws_rd=cr&ei=ZPFuWYyPJ4zM0gTxzbzIBQ#q=%22with+the+exceptions+of+*+and%22&tbm=bks&start=90) (even though some dictionaries use the singular version) and as @P.E.Dant said, we should not introduce unnecessary confusion about the numbers, I think I will choose to use the plural form, when there are multiple exceptions.

Comment: Then ask Oxford "Why you don't say 'exceptions' in your dictionary?"